# Change cell background depending on mysql field value

Tags: javascript, html, css, mysql

I have the following code and my MySQL table has a column (not showing) called **ativo**. I need the `$result_rowset['Nome'][$i] = $row['nome'];` to have background-color changed to red if `ativo = 0` and blue if `ativo = 1`.

Can anyone help me on this? I've tried so many ways found here but I couldn't customize anyone to my case.

Thanks in advance.

```
        <?php
        $result_rowset = array();
        $i = 0 ;
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $result_rowset['Nome'][$i] = $row['nome'];
            $result_rowset['Campo 01'][$i] = $row['campo1'];
            $result_rowset['Campo 02'][$i] = $row['campo2'];
            $result_rowset['Campo 03'][$i] = $row['campo3'];
            $result_rowset['Campo 04'][$i] = $row['campo4'];
            $result_rowset['Campo 05'][$i] = $row['campo5'];
            $i ++ ;
        }
        $result->data_seek(0);
    ?>
    
    <section class="feature-area section-gap" style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center" style="max-width: 1240px;">
                <div class="mytable table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                        <tbody>
                            <?php foreach ( $result_rowset as $result_key => $result_value ) { ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $result_key ; ?></td>
                                    <?php foreach ( $result_value as $val ) { ?>
                                        <td><?php echo $val ; ?></td>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

First u need still save the column `ativo` when you fetch array

```
 <?php
    $result_rowset = array();
    $i = 0 ;
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $result_rowset['Nome'][$i] = $row['nome'];
        $result_rowset['ativo'][$i] = $row['ativo'];
        $i ++ ;
    }
    $result->data_seek(0);
?>
```

and when you foreach the array you can add condition to make background color changed depends on column ativo

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ( $result_rowset as $r ) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <?php if($r->ativo==0){ ?>
                                  <td style="background-color:red">
                                <?php }elseif($r->ativo==1){ ?>
                                  <td style="background-color:blue">
                                <?php }else{ ?>
                                  <td>
                                <?php } ?>
                                     <?php echo $r->nome; ?>
                                  </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```